# Unable to require tag on server side in Riot JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, riot.js

When I declare: `require('./public_html/Tags/blog_post_details.tag')`, I get the following error:

```
E:\WORKSPACE\NETBEANS_WORKSPACE\MyProject\public_html\Tags\blog_post_details.tag:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <blog_post_details >
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\WORKSPACE\NETBEANS_WORKSPACE\MyProject\server.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

The path is correct because this line works `var commonsFile = require('./public_html/Tags/commons.json');`

WebPack config file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'public_html/assets/js/bundle.js'
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    },

    module: {
        preLoaders: [{
            test: /\.tag$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'riotjs-loader',
            query: {
                //type: 'none'
                //compact: true
            }
        }],
        loaders: [
            /*{
                test: /\.tag$/,
                loader: 'tag',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },*/
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    //commenting because of this issue https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3422
                   // presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            riot: 'riot'
        })
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The node `require` function only recognizes files ending in `.js` for Javascript files, `.json` for JSON files, and `.node` for binary extensions to the Node runtime. In the case of Javascript files, you can omit the trailing `.js` if the file or module can be found by Node's module system (i.e. under `node_modules`).

From your example, it appears that you are attempting to use `require` from client-side code. Unless you use `browserify`, `webpack` or another client-side bundler which provide their own client-side version of `require`, you cannot use it.

As noted in my comment below, the video link you provide shows *client-side* code loading tag files via `webpack`. You'll need to check webpack's config to assure it is properly bundling your tag files for delivery to the browser. Again from the video, the example code is loading its tag file from `./tags/filename.tag` where the root of that path is defined by webpack.

Comment: I see from this example(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6vpKAGT2-8) at 3:32....that using `require` for tags are working but I am not sure why its throwing error for me

Comment: The example uses webpack as a bundler. At time 2:09, it appears to be loading a tag file from a location local to the client (via webpack). I'd check the webpack config file to assure it is including your tag files in the bundle sent to the browser.

Comment: I already have webpack config. Updated the question with config details

Comment: Hm, the webpack config appears to load `*.tag` files, so my guess is that the loader code is case-sensitive. You have your tags under `./Tags` and it is expecting them to be under `./tags`

Comment: hmm I thought preloaders are loading it so I commented it out in loaders. Will compile and check

Comment: Also, it appears that the path to your tag files should be `./tags/...` and not `./public_html/Tags/...` though I could be mistaken. I'd recommend loading the example code exactly as defined in the video and then modify it to your needs.

Comment: I have declared Capital `T` for `Tags` everywhere...I am not finding any wrong paths

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139805/discussion-between-rob-raisch-and-kittu).